# Why are two different methods used to find the probability here?

Tags: probability

Given the same question of finding the probability of not obtaining two heads when a coin is tossed and if a tails comes up, a die is thrown, but if a heads comes up, the coin is tossed again, I found there were two ways of deducing the answer.

Method 1 was creating a sample set of all possible outcomes in which case:

Sample space S = {(HH),(HT),(T1),(T2),(T3),(T4),(T5),(T6)} and hence the answer would be 7/8

Method 2 was creating a Bayesian tree where the probability of not getting two heads would be

1/4 + 1/12 + 1/12 + 1/12 + 1/12 + 1/12 + 1/12 = 3/4

[image: See Bayesian Tree Here]

I seem to be getting two different answers but not sure which is correct. Is there something I'm missing? Which is the right way?

Comment: That last sum seems to be the probability of *not* getting two heads, isn't it? ¶ With that proviso, that's the right answer. In Method 1, you are assuming without justification that all the options are equally probable.

Comment: @BrianTung yes I seem to have mistyped the question, should be fixed now!

Comment: To emphasize... there are two outcomes when playing the lottery.  You either win or you lose.  The probability of winning the lottery is not $\frac{1}{2}$ however.  In general, the "formula" of $\Pr(A)=\frac{|A|}{|S|}$ is flat out wrong and this can only be used if there is proper justification that the outcomes in the sample space really should be equally probable.

Comment: If you do wish to phrase this in an equiprobable way... then regardless of the result of the first coin flip, continue by rolling a die anyways.  On a result of $1,2$ or $3$ of the die if a head were thrown at the start, call it a "head" for the second throw (*rather than calling it a die roll*).  For the other results, call it a tail.  That makes it now $12$ equally likely outcomes, three of which correspond to "two heads" and nine correspond to otherwise.  Depending on the problem however, this might not have been possible to reword in an equiprobable way, so you should get used to it.